# browser.bookmarks.create() does not create a bookmark in Chrome

Tags: javascript

According to [MDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MDN_Web_Docs), the `browser.bookmarks.create()` should create a bookmark and return a promise with the bookmark tree node when fulfilled. However, in this piece of code, the bookmark is not created. It returned some error messages to the console, but due to  my screen reader not reading them, I'm not sure what the error is. I checked on the MDN's browser compatibility table, and it says Chrome supports this feature.

Here is my code:

```
function bookmark(){
    let bookmarks = browser.bookmarks.create({
        title: "The Tiananmen Square (1989)",
        url: "https://www.theharnishes.com/"
    });

    bookmarks.then(function(){
        console.log("Bookmark added");
    }).catch(function(error){
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

The result should be that, when the promise is fulfilled, the bookmark should be created and the `"Bookmark added"` message should also be displayed on the console.

Comment: I'm going to assume that the `bookmarks` code only works inside of an extension, not just on a page.

Answer (score 1):

It will only be possible when done in the extension as it's a part of the `Browser Extensions`.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/bookmarks/create

Comment: is it possible to do it on a webpage?

Comment: Im afraid it's not possible, because it is a part of `chrome.bookmarks` API, which is designed for extensions only